# Возможно ли упростить данный запрос?

Tags: sql

хочу написать запрос который выведет всех людей, у которых есть животное с определённым кодом, если таких людей нет то вывести всех людей. Я написал рабочее решение, но оно выглядит слишком громоздких и не красивым, можно ли как-то это по человечески написать ?

```
select *
from people p
         left join animal a on a.id_people = p.id
where exists(select *
             from people p
                 join animal a on a.id_people = p.id
             where a.code = '3-1')
    and a.code = '3-1'
    or not exists(select *
                  from people p
                      join animal a on a.id_people = p.id
                  where a.code = '3-1')
```

Спасибо Гончарову Александру, в итоге получилось

```
select *
from people p
         left join animal a on a.id_people = p.id
where CASE
          WHEN exists(select *
                      from people p
                          join animal a on a.id_people = p.id
                      where a.code = '3-1') THEN a.code = '3-1'
          ELSE TRUE
      END;
```

Я затупил, понял что можно и так сделать

```
select *
from people p
         left join animal a on a.id_people = p.id
where a.code = '3-1'
    or not exists(select *
                  from people p
                      join animal a on a.id_people = p.id
                  where a.code = '3-1')
```

Comment: с такими условиями (кстати там у вас ошибки с exists в select не надо  обрачивать), можете просто убрать весь блок where

Comment: @Konst да, согласен насчёт select который оборачивает exists, косяк мой. Насчёт того, почему я могу убрать весь блок where не понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То есть false в условие where может получиться только в случае если `exists(select * from people p join animal a on a.id_people = p.id where a.code = '3-1')` = true , а   `(a.code = '3-1')` = false . То есть если во всей таблице(склеенной из двух) существует запись  '3-1', но данная запись не  '3-1', только тогда условие where = false. То есть смысл запроса выходит:
Если существуют записи таблицы с '3-1' , то вывести только их, иначе вывести всё.

Воплощаем смысл запроса кодом:

```
select * from people p left join animal a on a.id_people = p.id
where IF( 
     exists(select * from people p join animal a on a.id_people = p.id where a.code = '3-1') 
     , a.code = '3-1'
     , 1
 );
```

Учебный чисто пример для взрыва мозга, вроде. На то, что надо сначала смысл запроса понять, а потом перевести смысл обратно в sql. В реальности такие два разные запроса по сути в один паковать не будут даже яростные извращенцы, думаю.

Comment: О, круто. Спасибо, не подумал о таком, но это не учебный пример, просто адаптировал, чтоб легче понять было)